# Create a array of words using preg_match_all and regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I'm using the PHP function `preg_match_all()` like below to create an array which contains multiple words.

```
// the string which contains the text 
$string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit";

// the preg_match_all() function
preg_match_all('/([a-z]*?)(?= )/i', $string, $matches);

// debug array
debug($matches[0]);

// output
[(int) 0 => 'Lorem',
    (int) 1 => '',
    (int) 2 => 'ipsum',
    (int) 3 => '',
    (int) 4 => 'dolor',
    (int) 5 => '',
    (int) 6 => 'sit',
    (int) 7 => '',
    (int) 8 => 'amet',
    (int) 9 => ''
]
```

But when I debug or print the array with all words, the last word is removed from the array, in this case it will be the word "elit". How can I fix this?

Comment: Because there is no space after the last word. Why are you using the lookahead with lazy matching? Just use `/([a-z]+)/i`. Or to match whole words: `/\b([a-z]+)\b/i`.

Comment: Why not just use [str_word_count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) with the format value of 2

Comment: @CodeWhisperer I'm not getting the same result that you are. And looking for the regex there are more things wrong, like **amet,** which wont be caught.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `(?= |$)` as lookahead meaning a word is either followed by a non-word or end of input:

```
preg_match_all('/([a-z]+)(?=\W|$)/i', $string, $matches);

print_r($matches[0]);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Lorem
    [1] => ipsum
    [2] => dolor
    [3] => sit
    [4] => amet
    [5] => consectetur
    [6] => adipiscing
    [7] => elit
    [8] => Lorem
    [9] => ipsum
    [10] => dolor
    [11] => sit
    [12] => amet
    [13] => consectetur
    [14] => adipiscing
    [15] => elit
)
```

btw you can get same using split operation:

```
$tokens = preg_split('/\h+/', $string);
```

`\h` matches a horizontal whitespace.

Comment: this doesn't match all words, missing the ones that have a comma. Ex. `amet,` or `elit,`

Comment: Thanks, yes those words are not followed by space. I've edited it further.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following regex pattern to get all the words

**\w** matches any word character (letter, number, underscore)

```
preg_match_all('#\w+#', $string, $words);
print_r($words);
```

Will output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Lorem
            [1] => ipsum
            [2] => dolor
            [3] => sit
            [4] => amet
            [5] => consectetur
            [6] => adipiscing
            [7] => elit
            [8] => Lorem
            [9] => ipsum
            [10] => dolor
            [11] => sit
            [12] => amet
            [13] => consectetur
            [14] => adipiscing
            [15] => elit
        )

)
```

Comment: ping @Alex Andrei change the `#\w+#` to the correct delimeters `/\w+/`

Comment: that's a valid delimiter, see http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php, also I prefer it to `/` since I don't have to escape forward slashes :)